# how to escape key words in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I want to do the equivalent of the following VB in c#

```
Function([class]) "hello"
```

This *would* be the same as this in c#

```
class=>"hello"
```

The problem is that the word `class` is a key word in the language.  But I want to use it as a variable name.  In the VB example you can use the `[]` brackets to 'escape' that key word and allow it to be used as a variable name.

Is there a way to do this in C# ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add `@` to variable names:

@class

But it is a **very** bad practice. Every time you name your variable as a keyword a kitten dies :)

Comment: @Andrew Bezzub, I can see how it can be seen as bad practice.  But I need it for a very specialized scenario that will take way too long to explain the details here.   Having said that, I would like to hear your thoughts on why ***you*** think this is bad practice.

Comment: There is a reason why some works are _key_ words. the only reason i can think of to do this is if you're writing a compiler or some kind of parser. However, why is having a variablename which is not a keyword not an option, there are infinite many possibilities to do so. even using classInstance is better than @class.

Comment: @Roberto Sebestyen, all variables should have such names that it would be very easy for anyone to understand what is each variable for. I don't think having variable with name 'class' tells much about it. If you have a case when you think it can be useful then please tell me, I haven't met such cases in real world projects.

Comment: Another reason why you might want to use this feature: suppose you define your own domain-specific language, and then write a translator that translates your DSL into C#, rather than writing your own compiler. The reserved words of your DSL might not be the reserved words of C#; a user of your DSL might reasonably want to make a property named "class" or "event". If your code generator generates @class or @event then you don't have to work out some more complex scheme of encoding the translation from DSL to C#.

Comment: Without going into great detail, I am actually working on something that involves generating HTML, CSS and Javascript from strongly typed C# code.  The key word 'class' can be a key word for both in HTML and C#, which is why I needed to escape it in C#.

Comment: This is also necessary when invoking external members who's name conflicts with the languages keywords. That being said it is generally considered bad practice to name members with a keyword of ANY .NET Language (not just the one for which the declared member is written in). This is detailed in the [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) guideline for the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 7):

Use [@](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(VS.71).aspx) for reserved words:

```
@class=>"hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can prefix any keyword with a `@`.

But I don't think it's a recommended practice, and code analysis complains about it for sure.